# Jscript - checking for non numeric input

Tags: javascript

The following program accepts 4 inputs and if all the 4 inputs are numeric the program should sort numbers in order, otherwise (say if the input is an alphabet) it should display invalid entry.

Currently it displays Invalid Entry, Enter Only numbers, irrespective of what I type

Could someone assist please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <input id="num1" type="number">
        <input id="num2" type="number">
        <input id="num3" type="number">
        <input id="num4" type="number">

            <button type="button" onclick= "Val()">Submit</button>



            <p id="sort">
             SORTED NUMBERS ARE
            </p>

                <script>
                    function Val()
                        {
                         int a, b, c, d, e;
                         var text;
                         a = document.getElementById ("num1").value;
                         b = document.getElementById ("num2").value;
                         c = document.getElementById ("num3").value;
                         d = document.getElementById ("num4").value;

                            if (isNaN(a)||isNaN(b)||isNaN(c)||isNaN(d))
                            {
                                    text = "Invalid Entry";
                                    document.getElementById("sort").innerHTML = text;
                                    window.alert ("ENTER ONLY NUMBERS");
                                    //return false;

                            }
                            else 
                            {

                                     e = [a,b,c,d];
                                     e.sort ();
                                     document.getElementById("sort").innerHTML = e;
                                     window.alert ("SORTED");
                            }


                    }       
                </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `int a, b, c, d, e;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is correct, however your script isn't working because you used `int` to declare your variables, which is incorrect syntax in JS. You need to use `var` here.

just change to:

```
var a, b, c, d, e;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/88r21xn5/3/)

Comment: Hello, Initially I used var didnt work hence tried Int

Comment: Yes I did, the only difference between yours and mine is, the button tag is at the bottom in your script, so edited mine and changed the int to var, saved, still same. So copied your script and added html and DOCTYPE html tag and executed, same result as mine:(

Comment: If it doesn't execute you either have a syntax error somewhere in your script, or there is a problem with your html. If you upload your whole site somewhere for me to look at I'll find the error for you.

Comment: Hi Chris, I have uploaded the entire script in my first post.

Comment: The code you pasted still has `int` and not `var` like I told you. Here is a fiddle with the **exact** same code you uploaded above. I only changed `int` to `var`. http://jsfiddle.net/rd6rL991/

Comment: OK, my old code with var and your code works fine on jsfiddle, but I was testing by opening it in firefox and it does not give correct results (problem explained earlier). Any idea why it does NOT work on firefox - for example on jsfiddle it does NOT let me enter characters, but firefox allows and when I test,it goes wrong –

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work on your firefox. I tested it in Firefox and it works fine. Did my last fiddle not work on Firefox? Which version are you using? Does it work on other browsers?

Comment: hmm, OK all my prev code worked as expected in Firefox, except this! Tried   my code on IE worked like a charm:), so problem was with Firefox for this code alone. I am using FF-40.0.3.But I have one more question to annoy u, when i type alphabets and click, I expect the result to be invalid entry, but your code and my code (in IE), deletes the alphabet as soon as I type, so I never get to see "Invalid Entry etc",why is that please

Comment: @JScriptBeginner_25 it's because your `input` fields are of `type=number` and not `type=text`. This is why you couldn't type text before. However, some characters, such as `e` can be translated to a number ... (e ~ 2.7). If this answered your question, please mark it as "Best Answer" :)

Comment: Great it worked, so my initial code was right, just a browser issue and once i changed the input to text, I can execute the first part of if condition as expected. Thanks